# Changing font size in groff does nothing

Tags: manpage, groff

I have an unordered list defined in `groff`, but the system I'm on can't render the unicode bullet character, so I wanted to use a small <kbd>o</kbd>, and I've tried to use `\s-2` to decrease the typesize by two, yet, when I open said file with `man`, the `o` doesn't look any smaller than the rest of the text around it.

Here's the code I'm using:

```
.SH SYNOPSIS
.LP
\fIFiles\fP:
.br
.IP \s-2o 4
\fI\s+2File 1\fP
.IP
\fIFile 2\fP
```

Comment: Are you using `man` directly from the terminal, or are you using something like `man -H` or `man -X` to get output intended for something other than the terminal? Most terminal emulators can’t change font size.

Comment: Separately, it looks like it’s better to use `·` ([U+00B7 MIDDLE DOT](https://codepoints.net/U+00B7)), and use `man --ascii`  to replace it with a lowercase `o` if necessary.

Comment: @DanielH indeed, I'm just using `man` on the terminal.

Comment: In that case I would be shocked if you *could* affect the font size that way.

Comment: @AlexejMagura You should have added the command used to format and display the manual page.